# Is the field notation $(F,+,.)$ just a convention or has meaning?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

In an interview, I gave the following definition of field:

> A field $(F,+,.)$ is a nonempty set with two binary operations addition $(+)$ and multiplication $(.)$ such that:

- $(F,+)$ is additive abelian group,
- $(F\setminus \{0\}, .)$ is multiplicative abelian group,
- $a \cdot (b+c)=a \cdot b+a \cdot c,~~ \forall a,b,c \in F$.

Then one guy (who is from applied background) asked me the question:

> Is $(F, ., +)$ a field ?

In reply, I said:

> here $(F,+,.)$ is just a notation, the main thing to note that under the multiplicative operation $(.)$, the 2nd axiom is defined while under the operation addition $(+)$, the 1st axiom is defined and the multiplication is distributive over addition. So $(F,.,+)$ is a field as long as we are clear on the corresponding operations. We can simply use $F$ to denote the field once there is no confusion with the operations.

But the expert seemed confused in his question. I didn't clearly understood what he wanted.

So can you please explain your thoughts on the question ?

Is the notation $(F,+,.)$ just a convention or not ?

Was it a valid question or he misled the question ?

Thanks

Comment: "Is $(F, +,\cdot) $ a field?" What is $F$ here? It's a poor question.

Comment: It depends on the definition of a field. The questioner might have had in mind another definition, see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_(mathematics)). Then it is a valid question to ask, whether your definition and his definition are equivalent. The answer is "yes"  - and $F$ is this nonempty set of your definition.

Comment: In [tag:universal-algebra] it is customary to list the operations by decreasing order of arity, but that doesn't have really a meaning; it can be other order. Here, since the two operations are binary, it doesn't matter. I think your answer is correct.

Comment: @LostinSpace, by $F$ I am hiding the operation once it is clear. For example, when we say field of real numbers or complex numbers, we just say $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$. We don't mention the operation because these are clear

Comment: I think that the question he meant is this: "If $(F,+,\cdot)$ is a field under your definition, is $(F,\cdot,+)$ a field?" The answer is clearly "No", since the axioms you have given force $0\cdot a=0$ for all $a\in F$, which stops $(F,\cdot)$ being an abelian group.

Comment: @ancientmathematician, may be he meant it. But the question is controversial, i think. Because one can enhance on the operations, for, I clearly, mentioned that with respect to multiplication $F^*$ will be abelain group and with respect to addition $F$ is abelain

Comment: I don't think that abelianess has anything to do with it. You gave a definition of a field as a triple $(F,+,\cdot)$ and were asked whether that meant the triple $(F,\cdot,+)$ is a field. The question is well-posed and the answer is clearly "No".

Comment: @ancientmathematician, yes. But he could have directly asked whether $(F,.)$ will be a group in the definition (which is a simple question) because otherwise someone might get confused. Or he could have asked whether we can interchnage the operations.  I think it was a more trap than a question.

Comment: "Is $(F,\dot,+)$ a field?" is a sharp form of "can you interchange the operations?" I don't think it was a trap. You don't say what post the interview was for, if there were teaching duties they maybe just wondered how you'd handle smartass questions.

Comment: @ancientmathematician, I can feel it. Yes, if he just clearly asked "can you interchange the operations", then it was just as simple as $0$ has no multiplicative inverse and hence $(F,.)$ might not be group.

Comment: @ancientmathematician, Infact, at that moment I don't know why I just said that as long as we do not change the axioms in the definition, then the notations neither $(F,+,.)$ nor $(F,.,+)$ do not matter. I was only thinking it as a notation only. I agree my answer could be smarter as you said. I will take a lesson in future

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I would tell this person first is that in mathematics, notation usually (either implicitly or explicitly) represents real mathematical objects.

I might then give them one or two easy, well known examples, emphasizing what the symbols represent:

1. Let the symbol $F$ represent the real numbers, let $+$ represent real number addition, and let $\cdot$ represents real number multiplication.
2. Let $F$ represent the set $\{0,1\}$, let $+$ represent mod 2 addition, and let $\cdot$ represent mod 2 multiplication.

In each of these cases, yes, $(F,+,\cdot)$ is a field.

Then I would say to them:

> When you ask me "Is $(F,+,\cdot)$ a field?" my immediate response will be to ask you "What does $F$ represent, what does $+$ represent, and what does $\cdot$ represent?", because *your* question is unanswerable until *you tell me* what those symbols represent.

Now suppose we start using different symbols. I would emphasize that with the new symbols, written in order, the same principles apply. If they ask me "Is (GRACKLE,BORGWART,FNORK) a field?", I would say "first you tell me what GRACKLE represents, what BORGWART represents, and what FNORK represents. It does not matter what the *symbols* are, what matters is what they *represent*, as real mathematical objects.

So now let's suppose that we have an actual field $(F,+,\cdot)$ and they mix the notation up and ask whether $(F,\cdot,+)$ is a field, then the answer will be *no*. Show them how the distributive law of the operation $+$ over the operation $\cdot$ fails, because it is generally false in a field that $a + (b \cdot c) = (a \cdot b) + (a \cdot c)$. Show them how the inverse law for $(F,\cdot)$ fails (not the inverse law for $(F \setminus \{0\},\cdot)$), because $1$ is the identity element for $(F,\cdot)$ but $0 \cdot x \ne 1$ no matter what $x \in F$ is.

Comment: Ok, but the question is if we reverse operations. (And the answer can be the same.)

Comment: Thanks. In your, you meant $(F,.,+)$ not $(F,+,.)$, right ?

Comment: I added some to my answer to clarify that point.

Comment: @LeeMosher, thanks. So it seems that it is an ambiguous question, unless one clarifies. It has both edges, the asker is also somewhat true as well as my reply is somewhat also true.